# Openstack All-In-One local storage size

Tags: storage, centos7, openstack, openstack-cinder

after few deployment of openstack (packstack all-in-one) I founded that (from hypervisor summary) the local storage size is around 40G-50G. The disk storage that I deployed is actually around 150G and 250G but keep getting around 40-50G in openstack. The same behavior when I run over VM and baremetal. During OS(Centos7) installation I just using default auto setup...all storage size (sda) and never set manual.
For example this is the VGS output from VM with 150G storage running openstack

```
VG             #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  centos           1   3   0 wz--n- <149.00g    4.00m
  cinder-volumes   1   2   0 wz--n-  <20.60g 1012.00m

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               cinder-volumes
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  42
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <20.60 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              5273
  Alloc PE / Size       5020 / <19.61 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       253 / 1012.00 MiB
  VG UUID               rRywdY-5bzs-RnUo-P6p2-JshS-Hw79-zdaje8

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               centos
  PV Size               <149.00 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              38143
  Free PE               1
  Allocated PE          38142
  PV UUID               833flN-LOb9-qccj-wfdx-5fy7-UWB8-kcbsQe

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/loop1
  VG Name               cinder-volumes
  PV Size               <20.60 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              5273
  Free PE               253
  Allocated PE          5020
  PV UUID               mawPKG-IBfM-EWRN-pqXD-9hyD-ZL0q-vwgI99

lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME                                                                   FSTYPE       SIZE MOUNTPOINT              LABEL
sda                                                                                 150G
├─sda1                                                                 xfs            1G /boot
└─sda2                                                                 LVM2_member  149G
  ├─centos-root                                                        xfs           50G /
  ├─centos-swap                                                        swap         5.9G [SWAP]
  └─centos-home                                                        xfs         93.1G /home
sdb                                                                                  20G
├─sdb1                                                                             1007K
├─sdb2                                                                 vfat         256M                         EFI
└─sdb3                                                                 ext4         9.8G                         persistence
sr0                                                                    iso9660     55.9M                         VMware Tools
loop0                                                                  ext4           2G /srv/node/swiftloopback
loop1                                                                  LVM2_member 20.6G
├─cinder--volumes-cinder--volumes--pool_tmeta                                        20M
│ └─cinder--volumes-cinder--volumes--pool-tpool                                    19.6G
│   ├─cinder--volumes-cinder--volumes--pool                                        19.6G
│   └─cinder--volumes-volume--ae0fccdd--2b8a--4103--a50f--5475274eb215               20G
└─cinder--volumes-cinder--volumes--pool_tdata                                      19.6G
  └─cinder--volumes-cinder--volumes--pool-tpool                                    19.6G
    ├─cinder--volumes-cinder--volumes--pool                                        19.6G
    └─cinder--volumes-volume--ae0fccdd--2b8a--4103--a50f--5475274eb215               20G
```

Even with 150G hard disk storage cinder-volumes is <20g ...

From openstack hypervisor it show local disk usage is around 49G

Please someone advise me how to get bigger storage on my openstack. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by *storage size*? If you mean the amount of storage for Cinder volumes, adjust the CONFIG_CINDER_VOLUMES_SIZE parameter. The [documentation](https://opendev.org/x/packstack/src/branch/master/docs/packstack.rst) isn't clear about it, but I think the number is in Gigabytes. However, this only works if your root filesystem has enough space.

If you mean ephemeral storage, you also need to have a root filesystem that is large enough. I see that your system has three LVM volumes for root, swap and home. My suspicion is that your root volume (named *centos-root*) is too small. If that is the case, create a Centos installation that does not separate root and home and try again.

**Adding additional information to answer the below questions:**

The storage size reported in the hypervisor summary refers to the space available in Nova's instances directory, probably under /var/lib/nova (not sure). Which is on your root filesystem.

Packstack uses an LVM volume group as the storage backend for Cinder. The physical volume for that volume group resides on a *loop device* /dev/loop1, which is a file that resides on the root filesystem. Therefore, Cinder's storage does take up space in your root filesystem. Use the command `losetup -a` to see that file.

Comment: Hi...thanks. By default CONFIG_CINDER_VOLUMES_SIZE is 20G. I can change this for larger size (not tested yet). Another thing is local storage size in dashboard hypervisor summary is around 50G....is it referring to root size of my centos? so now openstack using 20G cinder volume (block) or 50G local ephemeral storage...as of now deployment is just a single VM with 150G total.

Comment: I will extend my root and see how it goes. Meaning that cinder volume is not part of root volume right...Thanks for pointing me out.

Comment: I added answers to the main answer.